# Create nav menu from course category LearnPress plugin on wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I have two course category Mathematics and Physics. Each category have course relevant to it type. I want to create Nav menu on my website via this category. I mean I want to take Mathematics and Physics to be as menu.

Example: While user click on Mathematics menu it show only which courses have category Mathematics.So on. Please check below snapshot:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to go appearance > menu and select your menu location than after you can see your categories in just left of the screen. you can select your category from the list and click on the add to menu. After it just click on the save menu and check on your fronted side.

check the screenshot.

[image]

If you are not able to see your category list in this section than you did the mistake in your register_taxonomy() function.

you are having three options.

1)you can use the custom links for menu.

2)second option is you can check with firebug your custom category is there with display none remove that css from firebug.

3)third option is check the plugin and customize the register taxonomy function.

Comment: Thanks Aki for replied. My category is Course category and it come from LearnPress plug in. I want to create menu from it like I create menu from post category.
![screenshot-1](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B76dVinekfFWWmFTbWp1U1ZGbmM/view?usp=sharing)
![screenshot21](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B76dVinekfFWOHpiNFowbThELW8/view?usp=sharing)

Any idea?

Comment: Yes now you are having three option you can use the custom links for menu.  second option is you can check with firebug your custom category is there with display none remove that css from firebug. third option is check the plugin and customize the register taxonomy function.

Comment: Thanks. I got your idea.

Comment: Let me update my answer so other can review it and please mark as correct answer.

Comment: I am new user with stack-overflow. I click on mark your answer, but  it display message "Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly display post score". And vote is not update. Any comment?

Comment: No issues may be your reputation is low due to that it is happening

Answer (score -1):

Found the quick and best solution for this. Please use this WordPress plugin - Custom Taxonomies Menu Widget by Ade Walker

This is available as Widget

https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-taxonomies-menu-widget/